# Apache Shiro doesn't redirect me to login.xhtml in JSF

Tags: apache, jsf, shiro

I'm learning `Shiro` step-by-step with @BalusC's [article](http://balusc.blogspot.tw/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html), there is no problem until I **turning it into *form based authentication*** as the [fifth part of the article](http://balusc.blogspot.tw/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html#FormBasedAuthentication) said.

I did exactly what the article said, but the shiro didn't redirect me to the login page, instead, it always shows `index.xhtml` whenever I run my web app.

Here's my code, I have no idea what have I missed.

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**shiro.ini**:

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

[users]
admin = password

[urls]
/login.xhtml = authc
/app/** = authc
```

It should have redirect me to the `login.xhtml`, shouldn't it?
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the exact url of your index.xhtml that is being used in the browser is /index.xhtml or /faces/index.xhtml (and not /app/index.xhtml/), then it is simply not secured and you need to add an extra line. Also, login.xhtml should not be secured:

```
[urls]
/login.xhtml = anon
/index.xhtml = authc
/app/** = authc
```

Also, if the url your entering in the browser is /, it is not secured at all.

Shiro looks at the url the browser comes in from, it doesn't know anything about jsf.

So if it is your goal to protect everything, the config should be:

```
[urls]
/login.xhtml = anon
/** = authc
```

Note that the order matters, the first hit is where it will react to. So the login should come first and then everything else, otherwise your login page will be secured as well.

Comment: I tried this but it still shows `index.xhtml` when I run the web app.

Comment: What is the actual url of index.xhtml that shows in the browser, is it  /index.xhtml?

Comment: I found that if I type `http://localhost:8080/shiroPrac1/index.xhtml` instead of `http://localhost:8080/shiroPrac1/`, it will be redirect to `http://localhost:8080/shiroPrac1/login.xhtml`, however, is there somthing wrong? It shouldn't have shown `index.xhtml` at all because I have not logged in.

Comment: It shows `http://localhost:8080/shiroPrac1/` in the browser when I run my web app.

Comment: Added extra suggestion in the answer

Comment: Thank you! It works! But can you tell me what do you mean when you said `your login page will be secured as well`.
What's more, could you tell me what is `anon`?

Comment: I now know what is anon after study the doc of shiro , but what will happen if the login page is also secured?  
I tried remove `/login.xhtml = anon` but everything is still work.  
The doc: http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-%7B%7B%5Curls%5C%7D%7D

Comment: Hmm right I forgot, due to the fact that authc.login = /login.xhtml is added, shiro will not secure this page. It is smart enough to recognise a login page should be anonymous.

Comment: I saw the java doc of `AnonymousFilter` and I think I know why login page should not be secured. So as register page, the register page should not be secured and I must add `/register.xhtml=anon` (for example), or the user won't be able to see the register page at all.
The java doc:http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authc/AnonymousFilter.html